# Connecting a C-wire to a Burnham Independence Boiler

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I would like to install a Sensi thermostat which requires a c-wire. I am planning to run a new thermostat wire, since the old one was 18/2. I am trying to figure out the correct way to wire the c-wire for the new thermostat wire, if possible. The wiring diagram for the boiler can be found here:

http://bostonheatingsupply.com/Burnham/Burnham%20Independence%20I&O%20Manual.pdf

The set up for my boiler is on page 30:

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Also, see the similar question [How to connect c-wire to Burnham Series 2 boiler?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/155514/how-to-connect-c-wire-to-burnham-series-2-boiler). It seems in this case that 24v power was able taken from an extension plug for unused accessories, which is not applicable to this situation as far as I can tell.

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Edit: Here are some additional pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring compartment on your boiler please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ThreePhaseEel. I have posted some additional pictures- let me know if there is anything that I've missed that would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Connect C to the wire-nutted bundle of yellow wires

According to the manual for your unit, the C-wire coming off your transformer is a *yellow* wire (we know this because the manual has it connected to ground, among other things), that is joined with that green grounding wire and a bunch of other yellow wires, including one to the vent damper plug.  Given that the vent damper connector is likely the plug we see at the bottom of your photos, based on the wire colors going to it, we can then deduce that the junction of yellow wires in your photos is where your C wire should connect to.

Comment: It is working properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciated this topic but thought I would add one more point. Yes, the yellow wires are the C wire, connected to one side of the output from the 24 VAC transformer. The other side of the output from that transformer is blue and should be attached to the red wire to your thermostat.

In my case, the professionals who installed my boiler had swapped the white and red wires. That didn't matter with an old-fashioned 2-wire thermostat. Either the thermostat connects the wires together (heat on) or not (heat off). With 3 wires, it matters which one is red (input supply voltage) and which one is white (heat control). Thus, when I hooked my C wire to yellow, it still didn't work until I figured out the swapped wires.